# How to align min in optidef package

Tags: alignment, optidef

When I use optidef package I can manually align constraint by using \mkern like:

```
 \addConstraint{\mkern-48mu  0}{ \leq \Delta \hat{T}_{ij}[l] \label{eq:const17}}
```

But for the objective function I can not do so. For example

```
 \begin{mini}[3]
 {\mkern-48mu  w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
```

only moves the w under the "min" but not the "min" itself. Does any one know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal document (that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile to see your current output? Not everyone is familiar with the `optidef` package and it's syntax...

Comment: \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage{optidef}
     \begin{document}

\begin{mini}[3]
{w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
{\label{eq:Example1}}
{}
\addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p}
\addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.}
\end{mini}

\end{document}

Comment: The location of optimisation problem type is fixed within the body design. It's possible to move it, but it's not entirely clear how much/where you want to move it to. Can you mock up something that resembles the output you're after? It'll make it far easier to understand what you're look for.

Comment: Try this and you will see what exactly I meant, I want to be able to move "minimize" to the left same as the way I moved the constraint to the left:     
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}

\begin{mini}[3]
{w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
{\label{eq:Example1}}
{}
\addConstraint{\mkern-100mu L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p}
\addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.}
\end{mini}

\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

If you want modifications to an `opti`misation `def`inition provided by [`optidef`](//ctan.org/pkg/optidef), I'd suggest setting the problems using your own style. It will leave the code a bit cleared and provide some ease with modifications.

Here's a view of your definition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini}
  [3]
  {w}
  {f(w) + R(w + 6x)}
  {}
  {}
  \addConstraint{L(w) + r(x)}{= Kw + p}
  \addConstraint{h(x)}{= 0.}
\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

Here is the above output replicated using [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{\textstyle w}{\text{minimize}} \quad
      f(w) + R(w + 6x) \\
    & \text{subject to} \\
    & L(w) + r(x) = Kw + p, \\
    & h(x) = 0.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

From here it should be straight forward if you want to move content around - place `\hspace{<len>}` (where `<len>` can be positive or negative) where you need it.

Of course, it's also possible to align elements within the construction (despite moving them around via `\hspace`.