# Fixing the position of a part of an equation in different slides in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning

I am using the `beamer` class for a presentation and `amsmath` and `optidef` packages.
I have two optimizations in different slides of a frame. I want to fix the location of the words "minimization" and "subject to" in that two slides and only change the location of what comes underneath "minimization" and what comes after "minimization" (objective function).
How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\only<1>{\begin{mini*}
      {x \in V}{\langle c,x\rangle}{}{}
      \addConstraint{x \in }{\mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}
     \end{mini*}}
     \only<2>{
     \begin{mini*}
      {X \in \mathcal{S}^N}{\langle C,X\rangle}{}{}
      \addConstraint{X \in }{\mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}
     \end{mini*}
     }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about the `optidef` package and its alignment mechanisms, so I came up with a straight-forward but maybe also somewhat hacky and probably by far not the best solution. The code is not very readable and it might therefore be a better idea to recreate everything using an array as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455486/47927).

Anyways, to make sure that the vertical alignment is the same, you can use `\strut`s. To ensure the same horizontal alignment, you need to have the same width for both outputs. This is not easy, because of the syntax of the commands, but can be achieved using `\phantom` and `\mathrlap` (provided by the `mathtools` package).

More specifically, with `\mathrlap{\langle c,x\rangle}{\phantom{X \in \mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}}` I create a box that is as whide as `X \in \mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}` which is the longest line in both environrments and place `\langle c,x\rangle` inside. This way, the first environment is as wide as the second and the horizontal alignment is fixed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\only<1>{
    \begin{mini*}
        {\strut x \in V}{\strut\mathrlap{\langle c,x\rangle}{\phantom{X \in \mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}}}{}{}
        \addConstraint{\strut x \in {}}{\mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}
    \end{mini*}
}
\only<2>{
    \begin{mini*}
        {\strut X \in \mathcal{S}^N}{\strut\langle C,X\rangle}{}{}
        \addConstraint{\strut X \in {}}{\mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}
    \end{mini*}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A smiliar idea which might be easier to read could be just to use `\mathmbox`es with some reasonable width:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\only<1>{
    \begin{mini*}
        {\strut x \in V}{\strut\mathmakebox[5em][l]{\langle c,x\rangle}}{}{}
        \addConstraint{\strut x \in {}}{\mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}
    \end{mini*}
}
\only<2>{
    \begin{mini*}
        {\strut X \in \mathcal{S}^N}{\strut\mathmakebox[5em][l]{\langle C,X\rangle}}{}{}
        \addConstraint{\strut X \in {}}{\mathcal{K} \cap \mathcal{L}}
    \end{mini*}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```