# Shifting issue in different slides in align environment in the beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning

I am using the `beamer` class. In the `align` environment, I have two parts with three slides. The first part is similar in all three slides. The second part does not exist in the first slide, it appears in the second slide, and it is going to change in the third slide. I want to keep the position of the first part fixed in all three slides and align the second part with the first part in the second and third slides. However, the position of the first part changes from the second slide to the third slide.

Using `\only` does not work and changes the position of the first part:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}

\begin{align*}
\uncover<1->A &B\\
A &B\\~\\
\only<2>{C &D}\only<3>{C &DEF\\
C &DEF\\
C &DEF}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
```

Using `\alt` also changes the position:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}

\begin{align*}
\uncover<1->A &B\\
A &B\\~\\
\alt<2>{C &D}{}
\alt<3>{C &DEF\\
C &DEF\\
C &DEF}{}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
```

Using `\uncover` only keeps the first part fixed:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}

\begin{align*}
\uncover<1->A &B\\
A &B\\~\\
\uncover<2>{C &D}\\
\uncover<3>{C &DEF\\
C &DEF\\
C &DEF}{}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
```

However, in this example, my second part is small, and if my second part is huge,`\uncover<3>` will place my second part out of the frame.

So, how can I fix this problem? Is there any way to write something over something else (overwrite)?

Comment: Please, try to create a MWE (add documentclass, begin{document}, required packages, and so on) so that your example can be compiled by just copy and paste. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the text from shifting, you could use a `\mathmakebox` to make sure that the width of the cell is the same on all overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}

\begin{align*}
A &B\\
A &B\\~\\
C & \mathmakebox[2cm][l]{\temporal<2>{}{D}{DEF}}\\
\uncover<3->{C} & \uncover<3->{DEF}\\
\uncover<3->{C} & \uncover<3->{DEF}\\
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(kudus to [@Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711630/36296) for reminding me of the existence of `\mathmakebox`!)

Comment: So helpful, cheers.

Comment: @khashayar You're welcome!